# Creating XDocument with XNamespaces

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

first i'd like to show you how my resulting XML looks like:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS">
  <env:Body>
    <dis:ExecuteSQLResponse xmlns:dis="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS">
      <BOM>
        <BO>
          <AdmInfo>
            <Object>oRecordset</Object>
          </AdmInfo>
          <Table />
        </BO>
      </BOM>
    </ExecuteSQLResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

How it should look like:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS">
  <env:Body>
    <ExecuteSQLResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS">
      <BOM>
        <BO>
          <AdmInfo>
            <Object>oRecordset</Object>
          </AdmInfo>
          <Table />
        </BO>
      </BOM>
    </ExecuteSQLResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I use the following code to create the XML:

```
resXml.Add(New XElement(env + "Envelope",
                                            New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "env", env.NamespaceName),
                               New XElement(env + "Body",
                               New XElement(dis + "ExecuteSQLResponse",
                                            New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dis", dis.NamespaceName),
                               New XElement("BOM",
                               New XElement("BO",
                               New XElement("AdmInfo",
                               New XElement("Object", "oRecordset")),
                               New XElement("Table")))))))
```

it's some vb.net code but should be the same in c#

my problem is the "dis:ExecuteSQLResponse" after trying and trying i can't figure out how i can remove the "dis" before ExecuteSQLResponse.
I mean the namespace is fine.. it should just look like this:
"ExecuteSQLResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS""
without the "dis"

my XNamespace definition:

```
Dim env As XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
Dim dis As XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS")
```

Comment: Why do you think that the prefix matters? It doesn't (or, at least, it shouldn't).

Comment: it's depended on the way the program handles the XML's and without getting my XML like i need it, i have to make huge changes at the business logic (yea maybe not the cleanest and best BL)

Comment: If the program cares about the prefix, then it is horribly broken. That's not how XML works. Is it maybe doing string manipulation instead of XML manipulation? It shouldn't matter if the prefix is "dis" or "abc" or empty.

Comment: oh wow.. i think you are right. i was blind on the rest while fixing myself to the NS Problem. sorry for that. thank you for opening my eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part :

```
New XElement(dis + "ExecuteSQLResponse", '->which correspond to dis:ExecuteSQLResponse
```

to this :

```
New XElement("ExecuteSQLResponse", '->which correspond to ExecuteSQLResponse
```

Comment: thats not the solution sorry. if i do it my result would look like this:
"ExecuteSQLResponse"
and not like i need it: "ExecuteSQLResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS"

Comment: Have you tried? you have this part: `New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dis", dis.NamespaceName)` that add xmlns attribute. It should output what you need: tag with xmlns attribute without dis prefix. I tried this in C#.

Comment: ok, I just noticed this solved one part but left this part with prefix `xmlns:dis`

Comment: thanks my problem is solved (if you like check the comments above)